# Xamarin.forms ContextActions] Can I block other TouchActions in ActionMode?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-actionbar, android-actionmode

When the ContextActions of Xamarin.forms is enabled on the Android device, it enters ActionMode.

In the ActionMode state, items under the ActionBar can be touched and items in the ListView can be selected.

I want to prevent other touches except ActionBar when I enter ActionMode state by long-clicking ListView item.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround could be disabling the listview's viewcell IsEnabled property upon either appearing the contextAction or firing listview items longpress event, and enabling it back at the end of each menuitem command. Sadly Xamarin.Forms's built-in listview doesn't have such events. The only remaining option might be writing a custom viewcell renderer or an item template container (say stacklayout) renderer and writing longpressed event feature for it.